# SyncTriggers payload of length 'X' exceeds max length of '204800'. Reverting to minimal format

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, openai-api

I see this error in the Azure Portal under the `Functions that are not triggering` report in **App Insights** and this is the Exception message:

```
SyncTriggers payload of length '225004' exceeds max length of '204800'. Reverting to minimal format.
```

To my surprise, it seems the internet has not seen this exception message before.

I know something about why it happens because my service has more than a hundred endpoints and this error only happens in exactly one of them, so it is clearly related to the special functionality in that endpoint.

It does not happen on every call. Some times it can work 10 or 20 times and then suddenly it fails. When it fails, it crashes the app service. I can see this because the subsequent log items in Application Insights are **FunctionMetadataManagerLoadingFunctionsMetadata** which seems very much to be a startup event. This runs about 10 times, indicating to me that it crashes again and again or rather attempts recovery unsuccessfully.

There is nothing more in the log related to the actual error. Only that it gives up after 100 seconds of calling this url: `https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions`

```
The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing
```

This question is not about "why is the call to openai failing?". Calls can fail and that should not mean that my app service becomes unresponsive, crashes and fails recovery 10 times.

The call that fails opens a stream and yields the response and this is in all likelihood somehow the cause of the behavior since this is what is special about this code as compared to the rest of the code in the function.

Here is my code:

```
await foreach (var token in api.Chat.StreamChatEnumerableAsync(new ChatRequest()
{
    Model = Model.ChatGPTTurbo,
    Temperature = 0.1,
    MaxTokens = 1000,
    Messages = messages
}
```

The ´api´ is an ´OpenAIAPI´ class from [this excellent package](https://github.com/OkGoDoIt/OpenAI-API-dotnet).

What does this error mean? Why does it appear? How do I solve it?

(Yes, I can avoid the error by not streaming the response, but that is a requirement)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue was a connection leak. Some connections were opened (to OpenAI in this case) and never closed. Others were closed fine. After a short time, this error would start happening. Perhaps it started working again when the connections were automatically garbage collected at a later time.

I still do not know what the error message exactly means but the cause of the issue seems clearly to be this connection leak as that leak is fixed and now the issue has stopped.